# How to optimize my sql query or database on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

There are 4 tables as follows: the table `[T_D ]` has about 5 million rows and other tables have less than 5000 rows; `[T_D ]` has three primary key columns: `c_id, datetime, a_id`.

The relations between the 4 tables are as follows:

```
table T_D 
(
     c_id numeric,        -- primary key, reference on (M_C.c_id )
     datetime datetime,   -- primary key
     a_id numeric,        -- primary key, reference on (M_A.a_id )
     data float
)  

table M_C 
(
    c_id numeric,     -- primary key
    ...
)

table M_B 
(
    b_id numeric,      -- primary key
    ...
)

table M_A
(
    a_id numeric,      -- primary key
    b_id numeric       -- reference on (M_B.b_id)
   ...
)
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008R2, it takes several seconds to run the following SQL statement. I have tried some solutions to fix this problem, but it doesn't work well, it still takes about 10 seconds to complete running.

How to optimize this SQL query, and to minimize the executing time to less than 200 milliseconds?
There are about 120 records in the date range of the following sql query.

The SQL query to optimize:

```
SELECT
    C.c_id, SUM(T.DATA) DATA 
FROM
    T_D T 
LEFT JOIN
    M_A A ON A.a_id = T.a_id
LEFT JOIN
    M_B B ON B.b_id = A.b_id,
    M_C  C 
WHERE
    1=1 
    AND C.c_id IN (102, 106, 234, 868,319, 347, 215, 162, 297, 372, 630, 280, 347, 572, 321, 239, 252, 724, 233, 39968, 191)  
    AND T.c_id = C.c_id
    AND T.DATETIME >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
    AND T.DATETIME <= '2018-07-05 00:00:00.000' 
    AND B.b_id IN (100) 
GROUP BY
    C.c_id
```

Any good suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: How many of those 5 million records are in the date range? If it is a small enough number, adding an index on T.DateTime might help. (You can't have three primary keys, so I assume you actually have a three column primary key). We can't really tune a query without looking at the execution plan.

Comment: about 120 records in this date range,three primary keys aready have indexes on them,is it right?

Comment: You can't have three primary keys. You can have one primary key made up of multiple columns - but it has one index, and will only be in one order. You need to look at the T_D table and check the indexes. If you don't have an index that has datetime first, then I'd make one and see if it helps

Comment: I have only one primary key including three columns,the default index would be created with three columns,right?and the order of the columns in the index has something to do with the effiency of query?

Comment: Yes, if the first column in the index is c_id, it might have to read all rows for each c_id you're checking, no matter what the date is. If you have an index with datetime first it has the option of reading just the rows in that date range, then filtering those by the other checks, which may be quicker. It is almost always a good idea to have an index for the option that will produce the fewest rows if that was the only check involved. If you run the query in SSMS and look at the actual execution plan, number of rows read vs rows returned is the telling point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relationship and data type seem ok.

M_B is the only table which is not related with T_D.

See if you have define FK constraint then no need to Join those table in query.

As per your visible query,main problem is your query

No need to use     M_C  C in query.

If possible use INNER JOIN or EXISTS clause.for example output from M_B and M_A is not require in resultset then you can try using EXISTS clause.

Since T_D has lot of record so put predicate in T_D columns which will improve cardinality estimate.

```
Notice :  T.c_id IN (102,106,234,868,319,347,215,162,297,372,630,280,347,572,321,239,252,724,233,39968,191 ) 

    SELECT
    T.c_id ,SUM(T.DATA) DATA 
FROM
    T_D T 
LEFT JOIN
    M_A A 
        ON A.a_id = T.a_id
LEFT JOIN
    M_B B 
        ON B.b_id = A.b_id  
--,    M_C  C 
WHERE
   -- 1=1 
    T.c_id IN (102,106,234,868,319,347,215,162,297,372,630,280,347,572,321,239,252,724,233,39968,191 )  
    --AND T.c_id= C.c_id
    AND T.DATETIME >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
    AND T.DATETIME <= '2018-07-05 00:00:00.000' 
    AND B.b_id IN(
        100
    ) 
GROUP BY
    T.c_id
```

Alternatively you can try

```
SELECT
    T.c_id ,SUM(T.DATA) DATA 
FROM
    T_D T 
where T.c_id IN (102,106,234,868,319,347,215,162,297,372,630,280,347,572,321,239,252,724,233,39968,191 )  

    AND T.DATETIME >= '2018-07-01 00:00:00.000' 
AND T.DATETIME <= '2018-07-05 00:00:00.000'

And Exists(
select 1 from
    M_A A 

inner JOIN
    M_B B 
        ON B.b_id = A.b_id  

WHERE
    A.a_id = T.a_id


    AND B.b_id IN(
        100
    ) 
)
GROUP BY
    T.c_id
```

Don't use `M_C  C` in join simple because it is not require.

There are several reason for "index not being use."
But we can optimize query.

Comment: If using T.c_id rather than C.c_id,in my point of view,I’m just wondering that it won’t use indexes of T_D when executing ,right?

Comment: @stkflmb12 most of the time Optimizer is smart enough to use.but normally if you have choice then put predicate in table which has more record to be safe. Also don't know that exact relation between M_A and M_B like one-to one or one to many ?

Comment: I have tried your proposal, but it is still running slowly. what is the diffenrence between them? if using 'T.c_id IN ()' , it won't use the index ,right?

Comment: @stkflmb12,check my edited answer. also what is the relationship between M_A and M_B like one-to one or one to many ?

Comment: The relation between M_A and M_B is one-to-many,but both M_A and M_B have small quantity of data,and it won’t increase up too much,so we may just ignore them.